# What does krausen say about the flavor of the final beer

Tags: krausen

...if anything.

I'm brewing batch number 4 now. So far I've tasted three different delicious beers with three different krausen behaviors, and the fourth yet again has different krausen. I'm just wondering if there are any early observations that an experienced brewer can make about the taste or mouth feel of the final beer based on the krausen?

Does more krausen imply certain types of sugars or proteins that will make the beer heavier or thicker tasting? Is it going to be a more malty tasting beer if it has a taller-standing krausen?

At this point I'm learning to just bottle and taste the beer. But I am interested in finding ways to get early indications about what the beer is going to taste like and try and shorten the feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any information you could glean from the krousen about the final product of the beer that you wouldn't have implicitly from your recipe and fermentation conditions. The strongest thing your krousen might indicate is the health of your yeast- although this is probably a weak indicator at best.